# Converting a JSON string into an object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a string object which is as follows:-

```
[{"TradeId":123423,"TradeDate":"2017-12-11T18:30:00.000Z","Commodity":"AL","Side":"Buy","Qty":100,"Price":2000,"Location":"NY"},
{"TradeId":123428,"TradeDate":"2017-12-15T18:30:00.000Z","Commodity":"AL","Side":"Buy","Qty":100,"Price":2000,"Location":"NY"}]
```

I want to use this as an array on which map can be invoked.
How can this be achieved.

I did `JSON.parse()` of this string, but I get an error stating the following:-

```
Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
```

When I do

```
JSON.parse('[{"TradeId":123423,"TradeDate":"2017-12-11T18:30:00.000Z","Commodity":"AL","Side":"Buy","Qty":100,"Price":2000,"Location":"NY"},
    {"TradeId":123428,"TradeDate":"2017-12-15T18:30:00.000Z","Commodity":"AL","Side":"Buy","Qty":100,"Price":2000,"Location":"NY"}]')
```

note the `quotes ('')` , from my node terminal, it works!!!

please note that I get this string from a websocket.

My end goal is to use this string as an Array on which I can use the map operation

```
socket.on('getdata', (msg) => {
    console.log("getdata",msg);
    //TradesActions.loadTrades(msg)
    myStore.dispatch(TradesActions.loadTrades(JSON.parse(msg.toString())))
})
```

After it is dispatched above(react+redux), its used is some component as follows:-

```
trades.map((trade, index) => {...})
```

Thanks,
Amar

Comment: It's already an object, not a string. Don't use JSON.parse

Comment: The error indicates that the value is already an object. See for yourself: `JSON.parse([{}])`.

Comment: But get this error when I try to do trades,map(...) trades.map is not a function

Comment: Also 'typeof trades' gives me string as output

Comment: Show us the exact code.

Comment: Where are you getting the value you're trying to parse from, exactly?

Comment: I have updated the code

Comment: What is `typeof msg`? And what does `console.log(msg)` log?

Comment: typeof msg gives string, console.log() gives me [{"TradeId":123423,"TradeDate":"2017-12-11T18:30:00.000Z","Commodity":"AL","Side":"Buy","Qty":100,"Price":2000,"Location":"NY"},
{"TradeId":123428,"TradeDate":"2017-12-15T18:30:00.000Z","Commodity":"AL","Side":"Buy","Qty":100,"Price":2000,"Location":"NY"}]

Answer (score 3):

`JSON.parse` assumes that whatever you pass to it is a string.

Your data is already an object. `JSON.parse` will cast said object to a string, then try to parse it. Basically, something like this:

`JSON.parse(obj.toString())`

Casting a object to string like that returns `"[object Object]"`

Now guess where the *"Unexpected token `o` in JSON at position 1"* error gets its `"o"` from?

TL;DR: Don't use `JSON.parse`. Your data already is an object.

Comment: My String is an array of objects, but I am unable to call the map function on it, typeof says that it is a string

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this.

The problem was not here, but in the part of the code that was getting the message from rabbitMQ using amqplib.

After getting the message I did a `JSON.parse(msg.content)` instead of `msg.content.toString()` and it resolved the issue!!
Thanks a lot everyone for their time and effort.